# how to traversal redis list

Tags: list, insert, redis

I have a list in redis, I can ensure the element in the list is ordered.Now I has a new element,I want to insert in the list and the list is also ordered. My way is traverse the list and compare the element.So how can I traverse the list?
I know the list has LPOP way,but I don't want to remove element.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use [LRANGE](http://redis.io/commands/lrange) command which will return all elements of the list in one operation (e.g. `LRANGE mylist 0 -1`) or use combination of [LLEN](http://redis.io/commands/llen) to get the length of the list and [LINDEX](http://redis.io/commands/lindex) to navigate through each element based on the number returned by LLEN command.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fetch all the data of a list from Redis, you do not need to iterate and fetch individual items. this will be inefficient and not a good practice to do so.

You can use the `LRANGE` command to fetch all the items in one command only.
Command is as below. Please have a look.

```
elements = redis.lrange( "supplier_id", 0, -1 )
```

this command will return all the items of the list without altering the list itself.